# Can the Sobolev Inequalities be derived from the Weighted Hardy Inequality, or vice versa?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inequalities

Here, for the weighted version of the Hardy Inequality, I refer to Muckenhoupt's formulation in Theorem 1 of [1](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm44/sm4414.pdf)

Sobolev Inequality: $$C_d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert \nabla \phi \vert^2 \geq \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \vert \phi(x)\vert^{2d/(d-2)} \right)^{\frac{d-2}{d}} \qquad $$

Comment: Theorem 1 in Muckenhoupt's paper is not the hardy inequality but a conditions equivalent to it. In any case Muckenhoupt deals with inequalities in dimension 1 while your inequality is in dimension $d$. You should find references to similar higher dimensional Hardy type inequalities and the literature is vast.